# Multiple users access same Mariadb database simultaneously

Tags: mariadb

I've a Mariadb database and I want multiple db users from different systems at the same time should be able to access db to write/read datas inside it.
Is possible accomplish that goal?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Almost all RDBMS support concurrent multi-user access (Sqlite and MS Access would be exceptions, if you consider them to be RDBMS).

Comment: Ok, in which way may I able to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent access is the only way to access MySQL/MariaDB.  You would have to do something extra to *prevent it*.

That said, there are certain protocols to be concerned about.

Multiple connections can `SELECT` without any interference (other than resource contention, such as CPU).

Multiple writes (`UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `INSERT`)  lead to contention among themselves, or sometimes even with `SELECT`.  In some apps, this contention is not a problem.  In others, you need to be careful to avoid "wrong" results.  A classic problem is transferring money from one account to another.  It should be performed by a "transaction" like this:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance - 1000 WHERE id = 234;
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + 1000 WHERE id = 765;
if ... then COMMIT else ROLLBACK
```

You don't want any other connection messing with either of those *rows* while *both* `UPDATEs` are being performed, hence the `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.

If you find something amiss, such is 'insufficient funds', or if the system crashes, you want a `ROLLBACK` so that these two rows are reverted to their state before the `BEGIN`.

Contention is handled in one of 3 ways:

- Allow simultaneous access (eg just `SELECTs`)
- "Wait" -- Some conflicts can be resolved by one connection waiting for another to release the row(s).
- "Deadlock" -- Some conflicts cannot be resolved simply by waiting.  In this case, one of the transactions is `ROLLBACK'd` for you.

See also `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`